# what is the importance of <Integer,Integer> in Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue()

Tags: java, sorting, generics, hashmap, comparator

I am trying to sort elements by their frequency

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int itr = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < itr; i++) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            String[] val = br.readLine().split(" ");
            Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                Integer temp = Integer.parseInt(val[j]);
                map.putIfAbsent(temp, 0);
                map.put(temp, map.get(temp) + 1);
            }
```

here I am sorting the  map based on freq and storing it back as a linkedHashMap.

```
            Map<Integer, Integer> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted(
                            (Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue())
                            .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                            (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));

            for(Map.Entry entries : sortedMap.entrySet()){
                System.out.println(entries.getKey() + " " + entries.getValue());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Below is throwing compiler error.

```
            Map<Integer, Integer> sortedMap = map.entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted(
                            (Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                            .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                            (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Sample input
1
6
4 -2 10 12 -8 4

Sample Output 0

-8 -2 10 12 4 4

Comment: where is the compiler error? You should get some output, why didn't you include it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>>
    Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>> comparingByValue()
```

is a static method and it requires `K, V` to set/correct/adjust the generic context correctly when it's used within one. Otherwise, it assumes `K` is `Object` and `V` is `Comparable` which is not what `Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>#sorted` expects. Note that the stream got `<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>` from either `map.entrySet()`, where the `map` is parametrised by `<Integer, Integer>` or the type of the result `sortedMap`, which is `Map<Integer, Integer>`.

`Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue()` gives the hints necessary to resolve it nicely.

`Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`, as is, is a very vague thing to write.

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Object, Comparable<Comparable<?>>>> 
     comparator = comparingByValue();
```

It becomes more meaningful when you give it a generic context.

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>
    comparator = comparingByValue();
```

In your case, it's important because `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` starts the chain, and the following instance methods (e.g. `thenComparing`) will resolve their own generic parameters based on the generic parameters of the preceding method (here, `comparingByValue`).