# HashMap Sort By Value of AtomicInteger

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I have the HashMap and trying to sort reverse order by value, and my below code work ascending order,

```
LinkedHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> collect = counterMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.getValue().get()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Unfortunately i couldn't use reverseOrder() in sorted method.

Any suggestion or idea's are welcome. thanks!

Comment: "i couldn't use reverseOrder() in sorted method" why?

Comment: Use this trick `...sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.getValue().get()*-1))`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko compiler throwing me "Cannot resolve method getValue()" Error. Hadi J's hacks works fine, and it's awesome. Thanks Hadi J. :-)

Comment: @parrotjack it's not *that* awesome ;) when there's a specifically designed method for that: `reversed()`. Have a look at my answer

Comment: @HadiJ besides the fact that `x * -1` is a verbose variant of `-x`, it’s a broken solution, as in case of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, it will *not* do the right thing. Since this is a particular rare value, such code may pass all tests, but suddenly produce hard to reproduce errors in a production environment.

Answer (score 4):

You need to help the compiler to resolve the generic types.

```
Comparator.<Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger>>comparingInt(a -> a.getValue().get())
          .reversed()
```

Otherwise, it assumes that `a` is an `Object` and `a.getValue()` will not compile.

[This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113660/what-is-the-importance-of-integer-integer-in-map-entry-integer-integercompa/58113938#58113938) I gave a few days ago is closely related.

Comment: Or `Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.getValue().get()))`